# .Net Core Web Apps occasionally stop working properly until re-deployed

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-webapps

This is the second time I've seen this behaviour now, and I'm not sure how to tackle this.

I have a web system based around .Net Core.  Currently 2.0 (I know, I need to update this).

- A single App Service
- Two .Net Core-based Web Apps:

  - Mostly Web API REST endpoints
  - One has some very simple MVC front-end stuff too (a back-end management portal which uses JS/JQuery to query some REST endpoints to provide some stats and diagnostics stuff)
  - One web app has two Queue-triggered Webjobs
  - Both access the same Azure SQL Database via EF Core.
  - Both use NLog for logging
- A third Web App is Just for an Angular front-end which handles the main UI, and never gives any real problems (makes calls to one of the Web API endpoints and displays the resulting data.. doesn't have much logic)

These apps form a multi-tenant reporting system.  One app is used to fetch data for reporting.  The other is an endpoint used by remote client systems to upload & import data which then becomes visible on the front-end.

Everything is built on a build server (Team city), and build artifacts are also deployed to azure via separate build configurations on the same Team City server.

This has generally been working well for a while now (over a year).  however a couple of months or so ago one of these Web apps (the reporting one) started not responding to requests. Not all requests (e.g. the basic things like 'login' which just generates a JWT token were ok), but anything that was trying to get much data wouldn't respond.

Re-starting the web app didn't help.  Turning on extra logging didn't help, but appeared to pinpoint that it was getting to a particular line of code and just... *stopping*.  It was extremely odd, and wasn't a line doing anything particularly taxing.

In the end I added yet more logging and of course had to re-deploy to get those changes up... and then the problem just went away completely.  I really didn't add anything extra besides a few logging statements (I'm fairly meticulous about this & have build/deployment history available through Team City/VCS Labelling (Git)).

Now today I ended up with similar symptoms on the *other* .Net Core Web app.  it seemed to just be getting to a particular place in the code then *stopping*. (as far as I could tell from the logs). After trying to re-start the app (and the entire App Service covering both apps) and it having no effect I simply re-deployed the site again **with no changes whatsoever** and it started working.

What might cause this behaviour?  It seems that sometimes the .Net Core Web Apps simply get in some sort of weird state and stop responding properly.  They don't throw exceptions, just... **stop**.  And re-starting the Web Apps doesn't appear to help, which is especially weird.  It's as if it's persisting more state than you'd expect between re-starts.

I'm going to try to prioritise an upgrade to .Net Core 2.2 or similar soon, but wondered if anyone had seen this, as of course I'll not be happy if it happens again after an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten all about this.

Since asking this question I have upgraded this service to .Net Core 2.2 and then to .Net Core 3.1.

These problems have not recurred since I updated to 2.2 as far as I can recall, so the basic answer is that there is *something* in .Net Core 2.0 which eventually breaks for some reason.

So really, this is a bit of a moot point now since 2.0 is long since EOL, but just in case anyone is in this situation... bite the bullet and upgrade it.

(2.0 to 2.2 was simple, 2.2 to 3.1 was more complex but not the end of the world)

Answer (score 0):

Cause of suddenly not working can only be tracked by looking at the back end logs and if needed may be collecting the memory dumps can definitely add whole lot of value.

But yes sometimes Asp.Net core application was unavailable for a period of time after platform infrastructure changes. That issue is related to an interaction between the site preload functionality and the Asp.Net core module in the IIS pipeline.

This is being tracked as https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModulowine/issues/260 for Asp.Net Core

Just to see if it helps , Place the following Applicationhost.xdt in the D:\Home\Site folder.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.applicationHost>
    <sites>
    <site>
      <application xdt:Locator="Match(applicationPool)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(preloadEnabled)"
            applicationPool="wwwsilkroadcom" preloadEnabled="false"/>
    </site>
    </sites>
  </system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try that.  One thing though: the apps aren't *unavailable*, rather certain operations seem to start then stop in weirdly random (but consistent) places in the code.  some operations (generally simpler ones from what I've been able to tell) will still run to completion fine.  Plus, wouldn't re-starting the app resolve it if it was a temporary outage due to infrastructure changes?  it just seems so odd, and any attempts to troubleshoot via adding/changing any code require a redeployment which immediately fixes the issue.  Frustrating....

Comment: I assume that link should be https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/260 ?

Comment: Yes this link github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/260 is correct